# C Programming printing pointers

Tags: c

I have this bit of code:

```
printf("Address for ptr_one %p\n", &ptr_one);
printf("Non-Address for ptr_one %p\n", ptr_one);
printf("value for ptr_one %p\n\n", *ptr_one);
```

output:

```
Address for ptr_one 0xffffcbd8
Non-Address for ptr_one 0x600042b26
value for ptr_one 0x19
```

From what I understand the first line is the pointer address, and the third is the value which is at that address. But what is the second line printing out exactly?

It was initialized as such:

```
int *ptr_one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr_one = 25;
```

edit: added initialize code

Comment: Depends on the definition of `ptr_one` and how it was assigned.

Comment: Nah, the first one is printing the address of the variable that holds a pointer to something else. The second prints that pointer. - Assuming of course, the name is actually representative of the content and it's been initiated correctly, like dbush said.

Comment: `printf("Non-Address for ptr_one %p\n", ptr_one);` this is the address that holds `*ptr_one`. `printf("Address for ptr_one %p\n", &ptr_one);` this is the address of `ptr_one`

Comment: The first prints the address of the variable ptr_one, the 2nd prints the values that is stored in the ptr_one as a pointer address value.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: yeah sorry that i didn't put in how I initialized ptr_one I though it wasn't important but it seem like it is

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like you have code along the lines of:

```
int one = 0x19;
int *ptr_one = &one;
```

(you've since edited your code to show the *actual* situation but it's functionally identical to what I've shown above (in terms of memory and pointers to memory anyway) so that I don't need to change it).

What you then have is:

```
(ptr_one "variable")
    |
    V
+---------------+     +-----------+
| ptr_one value | --> | one value |
+---------------+     +-----------+
```

with the following descriptions:

- **Address for ptr_one 0xffffcbd8** is the address of the actual `ptr_one` variable, where it's stored in memory.
- **Non-Address for ptr_one 0x600042b26** is the *value* of the `ptr_one` variable which is also the *address* of the `one` variable.
- **value for ptr_one 0x19** is the value of the `one` variable.

Comment: so it most likely invokes undefined behavior due to printing an int with `%p`

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the pointer's memory address, the second line is the address that the pointer points to, and the third is the first value which is at that address.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit terse and doesn't mention the type of `ptr_one`. Suppose you have

```
int x=10;
int *ptr_one=&x;
```

Then

```
printf("Address for ptr_one %p\n", &ptr_one);
```

prints the address of the pointer ie `ptr_one`

```
printf("ptr_one %p\n", ptr_one);
```

prints the address of `x` (`ptr_one` is a pointer after all.)

```
printf("ptr_one points to %p\n\n", *ptr_one);
```

prints the value of `x` (Here you dereference the pointer to gets the value stored in it)

Answer (score 0):

The **ptr_one** is an intiger pointer present in address location *0xffffcbd8*. 
Currently it points to an address *0x600042b26*. 
In address *0x600042b26* we have the value 25 in it.

This link shows [***how ptr_one***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KYtI.png) is allocated in memory

Hope this provides the answer..